# How to display the logfile in a browser YII

Tags: php, logging, yii

I need to display the logfile in the browser. 
I would like to do something like

```
    if(isset($_Get['showlog'] && $_Get['showlog']==1){
          $this_>redner('output', application.log);
    }
```

Is it possible to do this in yii? And how could I do it?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset(Yii::app()->request->getQuery('showlog')) {
          $this->render('output', application.log);
}
```

[documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getQuery-detail)